# Are there any loops or references is Batch?

Tags: loops, batch-file, syntax

I'm currently trying to learn Batch scripting and i wanted to know if there are any loops or references in Batch (example down below).

In C# there are loops like

```
while (true)
{ Tasks }
```

and

```
for (int i=0; i<value; i++)
{ // do ... }
```

and

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{ // do ... }
```

and

```
do
{ // do ... }
while (true)
```

and

```
if (true)
{ // do ... }
else
{ // do else ... }
```

and

```
try
{ // try to do ... }
catch (Exception e)
{ // do if try fails ... }
finally
{ // do anyways ... }
```

and

```
switch (value)
{ case 1: /* do */ break; case...; }
```

I want to know if these do exist in Batch and how the syntax looks or how I can use it.

Thanks
MC

Comment: Go read: http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/index.html

Comment: And then read http://ss64.com/nt/for.html and the related links at the bottom. `For` loops are the very core of batch programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few types of loops.  Most involve the `for` keyword.  Type `help for` in a cmd console for more info.  The most basic is

```js
for %%x in (tokenset) do (
    rem // act on each token
)
```

The batch equivalent of `for (var i=0; i<10; i++)` in other languages is `for /L`.

```js
for /L %%x in (0,1,10) do (
    rem // 0..10
)
```

There's no `while` or `do until` loop, but there is `goto label`.  For example:

```js
set x=0
:loop
set /a x+=1
if %x% leq 9 goto loop
```

And for looping through the contents of a file or the output of a command, there's `for /F`.

```js
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("filename.txt") do (
    rem // act on each line of text
)

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('command') do (
    rem // act on each line of output
)
```

In order of efficiency, `for` and `for /L` are fastest.  But if you break out of `for /L` using `goto`, the script continues to iterate through the loop until complete, but skipping the commands within.  This can affect performance if you're using `for /L %%I in (0,1,1000000)` and use `goto` to try to break out of it after a few iterations.  Example:

```js
for /L %%I in (0,1,10) do (
    echo %%I
)
```

is much faster than...

```js
for /L %%I in (0,1,1000000) do (
    echo %%I
    if %%I gtr 9 goto next
    rem // continues iterating 1000001 times, but only echoes 11 lines.
)
:next
```

`for /F` is a little slower, and `goto` is slowest.

---

You had also mentioned `if` and `switch`.  `if`, yes.  There is `if`.  Type `help if` from a cmd console for full details.  Examples:

```js
set /a "var = 5 << 2"
if %var% gtr 30 echo What a big number!

set "var=foo"

if /I "%var%"=="Foo" echo Case insensitive match worked with /I
```

There's also [conditional execution](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php), which comes in very handy.  Rather than checking `if errorlevel n`, you can check for zero / non-zero status with `&&` or `||`.  Example:

```js
(echo "The quick brown fox") | findstr /i "brown" >NUL && (
    echo Contained the word "brown".
) || (
    echo Didn't contain the word "brown".
)
```

There's no `switch...case`, but you can use `goto` for some creative processing.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

:begin
echo 1: option 1
echo 2: option 2
echo 3: option 3
set /P "opt=Enter a selection: "

for %%I in (1 2 3) do if "%opt%"=="%%I" goto run%%I
echo %opt%: invalid choice.
pause
goto begin

:run1
echo Do stuff!
goto begin

:run2
echo Do something else.
goto begin

:run3
echo Bye!
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

These don't all exist in DOS batch programming. You could use the following syntax for a for loop:

```
FOR %%i IN (list) DO something
```

For more, try [this link](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
:code
echo your code
goto code
```